# return not working properly when calling non-async function from async function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I am trying to do a validation where each 2 seconds, the app checks into the database for a certain value, until said value is found

```js
let conf = false;
do {
  await this.sleep(2 * 1000);
  conf = this.checkSession(hash);
  console.log(conf);
} while (!conf);
```

```js
checkSessao(hash) {
  let sql = "SELECT usuario_id FROM sessao WHERE hash='" + hash + "';";

  this.db.selectGenerico(sql).then(response => {
    if (response[0].usuario_id !== null) {
      console.log("suposed to return true");
      return true;
    }

  }).catch(ex => {
    return false;
  });

  return false;
}
```

the thing is, the function ALWAYS return `false`, even though `console.log("suposed to return true");` fires. I believe its related to the fact that i am calling a `non-async` function inside a `async` function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. You need to return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in your `checkSessao` function and wait until it's resolved in your loop.

```
checkSessao(hash) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let sql = "SELECT usuario_id FROM sessao WHERE hash='" + hash + "';";    
    this.db.selectGenerico(sql).then(response => {
      if(response[0].usuario_id !== null) {
        console.log("suposed to return true");
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        resolve(false);
      }
    }).catch(ex => {
      resolve(false);
    });
  })
}
```

Usage:

```
let conf = false;
do {
  await this.sleep(2 * 1000);
  conf = await this.checkSession(hash);
  console.log(conf);
} while (!conf);
```

Comment: Correct answer. Would be even clearer mentioning that async/await is syntactic sugar for Promise.